# Spring bean to compile all the regular expression

Tags: java, regex

If the compiling the regular expression is the most time consuming part, then is it a good idea to have a spring bean which will compile all the regular expression in the projects during initialization of the bean and make this (the compiled regex) available to whichever classes require for subsequent matching against target string? I have never seen any thing like that - most of time times, the class who is matching the pattern also does the compile at the same time. Is not it rather more time consuming to compile each time the pattern matching is done?

Comment: What if a pattern needs some dynamic text?

Comment: Sure, but most of the cases there are static text/patterns and I would like to move the static text/pattern compilation to the spring bean and if you have dynamic patterns then leave them alone.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen anyone doing this, would be a very special use-case to group your regex. if you have that many, and load them during initialization, the application will take longer to start, which could annoy the user. I have worked with large Swing applications before, there we made the initial UI load fast, and then starte a background thread which start loading all the classes, otherwise the UI could freeze 1-2 seconds when the user opened a dialog because it had to wait for a lot of classes to load. But i doubt you need background loading for patterns.

Answer (score 1):

It is always advisable to compile the regex once if you're going to use it multiple times.

Regex compilation becomes more expensive the more complicated it gets, and  most of the time we do it over and over without realising it. Case in point, these convenience methods (taken from [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=104)) always go through the compilation process under the hood:

- `Pattern.matches`
- `String.matches`
- `String.replaceAll`
- `String.replaceFirst`
- `String.split`

So you should always keep in mind the "convenience" methods you're calling and compile your multiple use regex once; either on startup or the first time that you use it.